# Delegation on form element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to learn React . I have a good JS knowledge , but know i cant handle a simple situation in React . I have put an event on form element , which has 2 children elements and i am trying to do something (it doesn't matter in this case) , so i have written an handler with its event object . I actually know that  the deepest element that triggers the event is called the "target" or "source" element and is available as an **event.target**. In my case event.target is not a **button element** , which is submitted , but the form element , which has an event on it. So i cant understand this situation .

Here is my code `

```
    const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const option = event.target.elements.option.value;
}

    let template = (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
                <input typa='text' name='option'/>
                <button>Add Option</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
```

It is supposed to me that event.target would be the button element , but instead of it , it is form element .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. Set a initial state `{ optionInput: '' }`
2. add an handler onChange to your Input and store the value in state
3. get the value from state when you need it (onFormSubmit)

   ```
   const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
       event.preventDefault();
       const option = this.state.optionInput;
   }

   const handleChange = (event) => {
        const {value} = event.target
        // Now set state - setState() 
        this.setState({ optionInput: value })
   };

   let template = (
       <div>
           <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
               <input typa='text' value={this.state.optionInput} name='option' onChange={handleChange}/>
               <button>Add Option</button>
           </form>
       </div>
   );
   ```

*Maybe you have to refactor the stuff with the `this` keyword. because I cant see if you using class Component or the more functional way*

Comment: If your example code above is all in render function then you should put _onFormSubmit and handleChange outside the render function_

Comment: No , i just wanna understand why the event.target is form element and not the button element , because the event triggers button element.

Comment: Because your `onSubmit` function is on the <form> component

Comment: The form element is triggering the `submit` event. Also in react-less code. see: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wXojzG